# Headphone Jack does not work

Tags: windows-7, audio

I just upgrade a HP Pavilion tx2000 64-bit from Windows Vista to Windows 7. This was a clean install and NOT a upgrade. Now both headphone jacks do not work.

I found the HP Vista Download page (I was not able to find Windows 7 yet):
http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareList?os=2100&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&product=3658348&lang=en

I tried installing the "Realtek High-Definition Audio Driver"
http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=ob-61929-1&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en&os=2100&product=3658348

but got a "Install Realtek HD Audio Driver Failure [Error Code: 0xE0000235]", which stopped the install.

Any pointers on what should be done next?

Edited:
I was able to get around the Error by uninstalling the Audio Driver. Once it was uninstalled the HP Vista driver appeared to install correctly on Windows 7 (no problems so far) and my headphone jack worked again.

Comment: You will have much better luck over at http://www.superuser.com, ServerFault's consumer-level sister.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always first check to see if the manufacturer provides the correct driver first. Since it doesn't appear that a Windows 7 driver is available, you could try the one provided directly from [Realtek](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/):

- Select "High Definition Audio Codecs (Software)"
- Accept disclaimer
- Download and install the Windows 7 HD Audio driver

Answer (score 0):

Try running the driver in compatibility mode for Windows Vista.